# Showing a single field from SQLite Database in an EditText

Tags: android, database, sqlite

first time posting here, long time lurker.  I am developing an Android app using an SQLite Database to persist data. The first view I have is a ListView where the user can add, change or delete Animal names.  They can also hit an Edit Button, which brings them to a second view.  This view has more details about the same animal, such as DOB and Comments, with the name and id transferred over from the first view.

The problem I am running into is I cannot figure out how to get the current animal's DOB and Comments to display in their respective EditTexts from the database.  I have a save button at the bottom of this view that should save whatever info they put into these fields already, but then going back into this view needs to display whatever they have entered.  My code for the two views and my DBHelper class is below.  Thanks!

Here are images of what the two views look like.

[ListView Primary View](http://i.imgur.com/yG9fsar.png)

[Detail View](http://i.imgur.com/ZClrvGI.png)

The MainActivity that contains the first view and the ListView:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
public final static String ID_EXTRA = "com.example.josh.boergoats._ID";
public final static String NAME_EXTRA = "com.example.josh.boergoats.name";

private DBHelper dbHelper = null;
private Cursor cursor = null;
private DBAdapter adapter = null;
EditText editAnimal = null;
String animalId = null;
long idAnimal = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        editAnimal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.animalEditText);

        dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);

        cursor = dbHelper.getAll();
        startManagingCursor(cursor);

        adapter = new DBAdapter(cursor);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        Button addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addButton);
        addButton.setOnClickListener(onSave);

        Button deleteButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);
        deleteButton.setOnClickListener(onDelete);

        Button editButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.editButton);
        editButton.setOnClickListener(onEdit);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(onListClick);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("ERROR", "ERROR IN CODE: " + e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    dbHelper.close();
}

private View.OnClickListener onSave = new View.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        Button addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addButton);
        if (animalId == null)
        {
            dbHelper.insert(editAnimal.getText().toString());
        }
        else
        {
            dbHelper.update(animalId, editAnimal.getText().toString());
            animalId = null;
        }
        cursor.requery();
        editAnimal.setText("");
        addButton.setText("Add Animal");
    }
};

private View.OnClickListener onDelete = new View.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        if (animalId == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            dbHelper.delete(animalId);
            animalId = null;
        }
        cursor.requery();
        editAnimal.setText("");

        Button addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addButton);
        addButton.setText("Add Animal");
    }
};

private View.OnClickListener onEdit = new View.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        Button editButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.editButton);
        editButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        Button addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addButton);
        addButton.setText("Add Animal");

        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
        //i.putExtra(ID_EXTRA, String.valueOf(id));
        i.putExtra(NAME_EXTRA, String.valueOf(editAnimal.getText().toString()));
        i.putExtra(ID_EXTRA, String.valueOf(idAnimal));
        editAnimal.setText("");
        startActivity(i);
    }
};

private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onListClick = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
{
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {
        animalId = String.valueOf(id);
        Cursor c = dbHelper.getById(animalId);
        c.moveToFirst();
        editAnimal.setText(dbHelper.getAnimal(c));

        Button addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addButton);
        addButton.setText("Update");

        Button editButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.editButton);
        editButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        idAnimal = id;
    }
};


public class DBAdapter extends CursorAdapter
{
    DBAdapter(Cursor c)
    {
        super(MainActivity.this, c);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor c)
    {
        DBHolder holder = (DBHolder) view.getTag();
        holder.populateFrom(c, dbHelper);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        DBHolder holder = new DBHolder(row);
        row.setTag(holder);
        return(row);
    }

}

static class DBHolder
{
    private TextView name = null;

    DBHolder(View row)
    {
        name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
    }

    void populateFrom(Cursor c, DBHelper helper)
    {
        //name.setText(r.getName(c));
        name.setText(helper.getAnimal(c));
    }
}
}
```

The second activity, DetailActivity, where I am having the problem.

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

private DBHelper dbHelper = null;
//private Cursor cursor = null;
String passedName = null;
String passedID = null;
private EditText passedIdView = null;
private EditText passedNameView = null;
private EditText dobView = null;
private EditText commentsView = null;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

    //dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
    //cursor = dbHelper.getAllInfo();


    passedName = getIntent().getStringExtra(MainActivity.NAME_EXTRA);
    passedNameView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameDetailEditText);
    passedNameView.setText(passedName);

    passedID = getIntent().getStringExtra(MainActivity.ID_EXTRA);
    passedIdView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.idDetailEditText);
    passedIdView.setText(passedID);

    dobView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dobDetailEditText);
    commentsView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.commentsDetailEditText);

    Button saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
    saveButton.setOnClickListener(onSave);

}

private View.OnClickListener onSave = new View.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        String id = passedID;


        passedID = getIntent().getStringExtra(MainActivity.ID_EXTRA);

        if (passedNameView.getText().toString() != null)
        {
            if (passedID != null)
            {
                dbHelper.update(id, passedNameView.getText().toString());
            }

        }
        if (dobView.getText().toString() != null)
        {
            dbHelper.updateDob(id, dobView.getText().toString());
        }
        if (commentsView.getText().toString() != null)
        {
            dbHelper.updateComments(id, commentsView.getText().toString());
        }


        //reset all edittext fields to blank before leaving
        passedIdView.setText("");
        passedNameView.setText("");
        dobView.setText("");
        commentsView.setText("");


        Intent i = new Intent(DetailActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
};

}
```

The Database Helper class, where the database is created and manipulated. Note that not all of the methods are being used, a few of them are from my experimenting.

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper

{

private static final String dbPath = "/data/data/com.example.josh.boergoats/";
private static final String dbName = "animals.db";
private static final int schemaVersion = 1;

public DBHelper(Context context)
{
    super(context, dbName, null, schemaVersion);
    //this.myContext = context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Animals (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT, dob TEXT, comments TEXT);");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
{
}

public void insert(String animal)
{
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("name", animal);
    getWritableDatabase().insert("Animals", "name", cv);
}

public void update(String id, String animal)
{
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    String[] args = {id};
    cv.put("name", animal);
    getWritableDatabase().update("Animals", cv, "_id=?", args);
}

public void updateDob(String id, String dob)
{
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    String[] args = {id};
    cv.put("dob", dob);
    getWritableDatabase().update("Animals", cv, "_id=?", args);
}

public void updateComments(String id, String comment)
{
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    String[] args = {id};
    cv.put("comments", comment);
    getWritableDatabase().update("Animals", cv, "_id=?", args);
}

public void delete(String id)
{
    getWritableDatabase().delete("Animals", "_id=?", new String[] {id});
}
public Cursor getAll()
{
    return(getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT _id, name FROM Animals", null));
}

public Cursor getAllInfo()
{
    return(getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT _id, name, dob, comments FROM Animals", null));
}

public String getAnimal(Cursor c)
{
    return(c.getString(1));
}

public String getDob(Cursor c)
{
    return(c.getString(2));
}

public String getComments(Cursor c)
{
    return(c.getString(3));
}

public Cursor getById(String id)
{
    String[] args = {id};
    return(getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT _id, name FROM Animals WHERE _id=?", args));
}

}
```

Thank you again in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I do, to use the same activity to add or edit (which I believe is what you're trying to do), is to pass, via an Intent Extra, the respective option and then have the code set the respective values. here's an example :-

```
        String caller = getIntent().getStringExtra("Caller");

        if(getIntent().getStringExtra("Caller").equals("ShopListByCursorActivityUpdate")) {
            ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.ase_storename_input)).setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("ShopName"));
            ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.ase_storeorder_input)).setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("ShopOrder"));
            ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.ase_storestreet_input)).setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("ShopStreet"));
            ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.ase_storecity_input)).setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("ShopCity"));
            ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.ase_storestate_input)).setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("ShopState"));
            ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.ase_storephone_input)).setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("ShopPhone"));
            ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.ase_storenotes_input)).setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("ShopNotes"));
            setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.title_activity_shop_edit));
        }
```

The 2nd Line checks for the **Update** mode (ie what is in the Intent Extra named **Caller** (extracted into **caller**)) and then sets the respective values which themselves are in Intent Extras. 1st line isn't needed I just had it there for debugging purposes.

Note the when called by Edit as opposed to Add then the Intent Extra `Caller` is set to **ShopListByCursorActivityUpdate** when adding is is set to **ShopListByCursorActivity**.

PS You may have issues in the first activity not displaying the changed/saved data as it doesn't appear that you refresh the data. In brief, if this is an issue. You need to rebuild the cursor (ie redo the query) and then get the adapter to use the new/amended cursor via `changeCursor`, `SwapCursor` or `notifyDataSetChanged`. eg :-

```
Cursor csr = shopperdb.getShopsAsCursor();
currentsca.swapCursor(csr);
```

---

In regards to comment

> You are on the right track, but I was actually having trouble putting the information that I needed into the Intent Extra. Since I don't have the DOB or comments field on my first activity, I need to pull that information from my database and put it into the Intent Extra somehow. Those 2 fields are created in my DBHelper class. Also, depending on how they can be pulled from the database, they may not even need to be put in the Intent Extra if they can be put straight into my EditTexts.

Then Use `SELECT * FROM Animals` to get all columns in getAll then all columns will be available in the returned Cursor.

Comment: Sorry if any edits confused you. I just realised that I duplicated setting the EditTexts.

Comment: I should have been more clear when I specified my issue.  You are on the right track, but I was actually having trouble putting the information that I needed into the Intent Extra.  Since I don't have the DOB or comments field on my first activity, I need to pull that information from my database and put it into the Intent Extra somehow.  Those 2 fields are created in my DBHelper class.  Also, depending on how they can be pulled from the database, they may not even need to be put in the Intent Extra if they can be put straight into my EditTexts.  Thanks for your original reply!

Comment: Use `SELECT * FROM Animals` to get all columns in `getAll` then all columns will be available in the returned Cursor.

Comment: PS Noted that you have `cursor.requery`, this, I believe, is deprecated so you may have issues with that (`changeCursor`, `swapCursor` or 'notifyDataSetChanged()' is the way to replace requery). Persoanlly I use `swapCursor` (got this working first). However, many say use 'notifyDataSetChanged()' (not tried it myself).

Comment: Perfect, I knew it would be something simple like that.  And good catch for the alternative to cursor.requery as well. Thanks so much!